# Simplest way to set a background image on a ProMotion screen?

Tags: rubymotion, rmq, rubymotion-promotion

I just want to set a background image on a screen for a placeholder. What is the quickest, easiest, simplest way to do that? Everything I've tried does not seem to work.

I should mention that this is in RedPotion so I already have access to RMQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do exactly this in RedPotion for my RubyTrivia app.  Simply set your root_view style for your given RedPotion stylesheet.  In this case I'm setting the background image to an image resource.

```
# In an RMQ Stylesheet
def root_view(st)
  st.background_image = image.resource('retina_wood')
end

# In a ProMotion Screen
def on_load
  find(view).style {|st| st.background_image = image.resource('retina_wood') }
end
```

Note that [the RMQ implementation of `background_image=`](https://github.com/infinitered/rmq/blob/master/motion/ruby_motion_query/stylers/ui_view_styler.rb#L230-L232) sets the background to be a tiling (repeating) background image. So if you want to fill the screen, you will want to use a different approach as it will look differently on different sized screens.
My RubyTrivia app is open source, so please enjoy!
https://github.com/IconoclastLabs/rubytrivia

Comment: Is there a way to do this without creating a style sheet class?

Comment: if you're using redpotion, you should embrace stylesheets when possible.   If you take a look at what RMQ is doing there, you can simply do that in your `on_load` to bypass the need of a stylesheet:  https://github.com/infinitered/rmq/blob/master/motion/ruby_motion_query/stylers/ui_view_styler.rb#L230-L232

Comment: O btw, you can style anything without using a class.   You can do `rmq(self).style { |me|  me.background_image = image.resource('taco') }` which is still RMQ styles, but no class.

Comment: Oh awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for. I'm using style sheets in other parts of the app but in this case I was just looking for a one-liner.

Comment: Also, thanks for open-sourcing your app. I'm learning a lot by simply browsing the source. =]